# Help Parsing a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I will have a string like this:

```
Bob is a boy. Bob is 1000 years old! <b>Bob loves you!</b> Do you love bob?
```

I want to parse it into an array, using the following delimiters to identify each array element:

```
.
!
?
<b> and </b>
```

So I will have an array with the following structure:

```
[0]Bob is a boy.
[1]Bob is 1000 years old!
[2]Bob loves you!
[3]Do you love bob?
```

Any ideas?

As you can see, i'd like the text between `<b>` and `</b>` to be extracted, previously I'm using the following regexp to do it:

```
preg_match_all(":<b>(.*?)</b>:is", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to strip the tags out first, then process the resulting string?  With this input it wouldn't make a difference, but for others it might.  For the input `<b>Bob</b> loves you!`, would you expect one line of output or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should accomplish what you're going for:

```
$string = 'Bob is a boy. Bob is 1000 years old! <b>Bob loves you!</b> Do you love bob?'; 

// parser
$array = preg_split('/[\.|\!\?]|[\s]*<b>|<\/b>[\s]*/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach ($array as $key => $element) $array[$key] = trim($element[0]).substr($string,$element[1]+strlen($element[0]),1);

print_r($array);
```

It yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob is a boy.
    [2] => Bob is 1000 years old!
    [4] => Bob loves you!
    [6] => Do you love bob?
)
```

The first line of the parser grabs each of the strings of text between the delimiters and their offsets in the string. The second line adds the punctuation marks from the original string to the end of each element.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody provides a better solution, this almost works:

```
(?:<b>|[.!?]*)((?:[^<]+?)(?:[.!?]+|</b>))\s+
```

Only it would return `Bob loves you!</b>` in third match, which can be cleaned by applying `strip_tags()` to results I guess...

Comment: Can't you move the closing brackets before the </b> so that it isn't captured?

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer?

assume $myString is your string...

First grab your  quoted stuff:

```
preg_match (" /(.*?)<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)/", $myString);
```

now you have $1, $2, and $3

```
$firstMatches = preg_split("/[\.\!\?]/", $1);

$lastMatches = preg_split("/[\.\!\?]/", $3);
```

Then get your punctuation back:

```
function addPunctuation($matches, $myString)
{
    $punctuadedResults = array();
    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
       $position = strpos( $myString, $match);
       #position is the offset of the start of your match. Find the character after your match.
       $punctMark = substr($myString, $position + length($match), 1);
       $punctuadedResults[] = $match . $punctMark;

    }
    return $punctuadedResults;
}


$allMatches = addPunctuation($firstMatches, $myString);
$allMatches[] = $2;

$allMatches = array_merge($allMatches, addPunctuation($lastMatches, $myString) );
```